# tag adding fails

Tags: bug, tags, editing

### steps to reproduce the bug

1. click "edit" on [Can anyone identify this object?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/17561/can-anyone-identify-this-object)
2. try adding 1 tag (as an edit suggestion)

### result

error message: *"edits must be at least 6 characters"* (red rectangle around composition window)

### suspected source of the bug

My hunch is that the bug occurs when questions have the [accidents](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accidents) or [accident-investigation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accident-investigation) tags, because adding tags to all other questions works just fine, whereas theses tags trigger a yellow warning message.

- When adding 1 tag as an edit suggestion for THIS QUESTION, I get the red rectangle ("at least 6 chars") around the composition box and the yellow warning text below the tags - related to the preexisting accident and accident-investigation tags.
- For ALL OTHER QUESTIONS (without these tags) I can add 1 tag (and add zero characters to the question) as an edit suggestion without getting either one of these errors (i.e. no red red or yellow warning). I have done this many times. Therefore I suspect this to be the source of the bug.

Comment: Can this bug please be investigated? Because as can be seen from the discussion below Glorfindel's answer, I think this is a separate bug. (I couldn't find a zero-with character even using a hex-editor).

Comment: If you or anyone else ever encounters this issue in the future, I recommend flagging for a moderator to perform a null edit. This will perform whatever Markdown-to-HTML update that the system was thinking you're trying to perform (and thus prevent you from editing), and allow you to submit your edit.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem on another Stack Exchange and asked about it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303041/295232).

> There was a single zero-width space at the end of the post body. These are stripped on submission now... Unfortunately, that's done *before* the system compares the revisions to see what has changed. So it saw the tag edits *and* a one-character body edit.

As a sub-2k user, you can't make one-character body edits (unless you edit the title as well), that's why you get the error message. It will only happen on relatively old posts, irrespective of the tags.

[The powers that be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_powers_that_be_(phrase)) might have deemed it not important enough to fix this bug, since there are numerous workarounds:

- find something else to fix in the post (e.g. a more specific title)

  - this fix by itself might be rejected as 'too minor', so be sure to specify in the edit summary that you're only doing this to avoid this very problem
- find somebody with enough reputation to make the desired change (e.g. in chat)

Comment: thanks. you reported this bug more than 1 year ago. So it still hasn't been fixed ?

Comment: I think 'they' have deemed it not important enough to fix, since there are numerous workarounds: find something else to fix in the post (e.g. a more specific title), find somebody with enough reputation to make the desired change (e.g. in chat)...

Comment: Upon further investigation, I don' think this is the same bug. You say the bug is related to the age of the question, irrespective of tags. But this question is from August 2015 whereas I successfully tagged [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2623/how-did-the-aaib-assist-in-locating-mh370) from March 2014.

Comment: Well, that last question didn't have a zero-width space, then.

Comment: re: *"find something else to fix in the post"* most of the time, there is nothing else to "fix" and it shouldn't be the requirement for adding a tag at any rate. (Case in point: do you see another useful edit in the question we are talking about? if it's not a substantial, useful edit, it will be rejected most of the time)

Comment: Didn't you say the zero-width space *"only happens on relatively old posts"* ? How does that rhyme with a newer question suffering from this bug when an older question doesn't ?

Comment: It doesn't happen *all the time*. Some old posts have zero-width spaces (or other stripped characters), some don't. You'll only experience this bug with posts that have them.

Comment: I have pasted the body text into a hex editor. There is no zero-width space in this question.

Comment: I'll ping Shog on the answer to my Meta question and see if he can comment here as well.

Comment: thank you, that is very helpful!